# Select results from table ONLY if rows meet 2 conditions

Tags: sql-server, relational-division

```
**OrdersTable**
  OrderID
  Product

SELECT OrderId, Product
FROM OrdersTable
WHERE Product = 'ProductA'
AND Product = 'ProductB' --doesn't work as AND looks for the same data in one row

OrderID   Product
-----------------
628       ProductB
628       ProductA
```

I am trying to query OrderID's that contain BOTH Product 'A' AND Product 'B'.
I've tried using EXISTS, AND/OR, etc but they always return an either or situation (i.e. the query returns orders that have a Product 'A', but not a Product 'B' or vice versa). How can I query only OrderID's that contain both Products A and B?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate for that:

```
SELECT OrderId
FROM OrdersTable
WHERE Product in ('ProductA', 'ProductB')
group by orderid
having count(distinct Product) = 2;
```

This will give you those orders that include **at least** those two products. The orders might include other products as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine results from 2 separate rows, so you need either `JOIN` or `INTERSECT` or something similar:

```
SELECT a.OrderId
FROM
        OrdersTable AS a
    JOIN
        OrdersTable AS b
    ON a.OrderId = b.OrderId
WHERE a.Product = 'ProductA'
  AND b.Product = 'ProductB' ;

SELECT OrderId
FROM OrdersTable
WHERE Product = 'ProductA'
INTERSECT
SELECT OrderId
FROM OrdersTable
WHERE Product = 'ProductB' ;
```

Using `AND` with `EXISTS` subqueries should work as well:

```
SELECT a.OrderId
FROM OrdersTable AS a
WHERE a.Product = 'ProductA'
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM OrdersTable AS b
        WHERE a.OrderId = b.OrderId
          AND b.Product = 'ProductB'
      ) ;
```

And yes, there's also a method with `IN` and `GROUP BY` without subqueries, which nah, I won't bother adding.

Answer (score 0):

why do not you try the IN clause.
regards
--QUERY

`DECLARE @TESTTABLE TABLE(OrderId INT,Product NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE VALUES(1,'ProductA')
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE VALUES(1,'ProductB')
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE VALUES(3,'ProductC')
SELECT OrderId, Product
FROM @TESTTABLE
WHERE Product IN('ProductA','ProductB')`

Comment: That will also return orders that only have one of those products.